# how to reinitialize a variable with new expression in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to do the following thing the bash shell. Plz tell me how can I do this ?

```
  ramsize=4002
  ramsize=ramsize/1000
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want to store in `$ramsize`: the integer division (4) or the float division (4.002)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **expr**
Like this :

```
  $ SIZE="4002"
  $ DIV=$(expr "$SIZE" / "1000" )
  $ MOD=$(expr "$SIZE" % "1000" )
  $ echo $DIV
  4
  $ echo $MOD
  2
```

back to your example:

```
 $ ramsize=4002
 $ ramsize=$( expr "$ramsize" / "1000" )                    //ramsize = 4
```

Update the last statement according to konsolebox comment ,

the last line **before** modification :

`$ ramsize=$("$ramsize" / "1000" )`

the last line **after** modification :

`$ ramsize=$(expr "$ramsize" / "1000" )`

Comment: * `ramsize=$(("$ramsize" / "1000" ))`. And `(( ramsize = ramsize / 1000 ))` is more efficient, especially `(( ramsize /= 1000 ))`.

Comment: * `ramsize=$(( $ramsize / 1000 ))` it doesn't works when you quote vars [see Arithmetic Expansion](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_4.html#SEC29),  i think C-style (()) for loops aren't POSIX , can you please explain to me why c style is more efficient?

Comment: Probably because everything (calculations and assignments) occur in a single scope. With `ramsize=$(( $ramsize / 1000 ))`, `$(())` would still pass the expanded value to the function that assigns the value to `$ramsize`.

Comment: Actually i didnt see that i forgot `expr`, and with your comment i realized that there is something wrong :)

Comment: `expr` is essentially obsolete for arithmetic, as all of its functions (other than regular-expression matching) have been incorporated into the POSIX shell via the `$((...))` expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$ v=2000
$ (( v/=1000 ))
$ echo $v
2
```

In your case:

```
$ ramsize=4002
$ (( ramsize/=1000 ))
$ echo $ramsize
4
```

Answer (score 1):

With floats:

```
ramsize=4002
ramsize=$(echo "scale=4; $ramsize / 1000" | bc)
echo "$ramsize"  ## Outputs 4.0020
```

Comment: Hot to do the following ramsize=16000
    freesize=3000
    cachesize=8
    ramsize=ramsize/1000
    cachesize=freesize/1000